# How to handle apostrophe ( ' ) in XMl and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an XML file which has details of employees and the problem I am try to figure it out is these XML values have apostrophe ( `'` ) in random places all over the XML content, so it's getting hard to insert them into SQL Server tables.

I will be sending this entire XML content from MVC C# to a SQL Server stored procedure which will insert the data into various tables, but whenever there is an apostrophe ( `'` ) in XML content, the error occurs. So these apostrophes  should be either handled or replaced or removed. How can I do this?

This is some sample XML content:

```
<xml>
    <Channel>
        <Program id="1" category="A">
            <name>Pra'Matino</name>
            <Bin>
                <Date>1/1/2020</Date>
                <Date>1/1/2020</Date>
            </Bin>
            <Player>
                <Pla>S'Rajesh</Pla>
                <Pla>Su'man</Pla>
            </Player>
            <Television>
                <HostDeails>2/9/2020</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>MALE</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>Colour</HostDeails>
            </Television>
            <addresses>
                <address>
                    <address1>No 10</address1>
                    <city>Chennai</city>
                    <country>IN's</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender's</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 72</address1>
                    <city>Sanagoor Road</city>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>Old No 10/ New No 3</address1>
                    <city>Madurai</city>
                    <country>IN</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 98</address1>
                    <city>BridhSanagoor Road</city>
                    <country>SriLanka</country>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
            </addresses>
        </Program>
        <Program id="25" category="B">
            <name>Rahman'G</name>
            <Bin>
                <Date>10/1/2020</Date>
                <Date>1/12/1989</Date>
            </Bin>
            <Player>
                <Pla>Paul'D</Pla>
                <Pla>Right'F</Pla>
            </Player>
            <Television>
                <HostDeails>5/7/2021</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>MALE</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>C'olour</HostDeails>
            </Television>
            <addresses>
                <address>
                    <address1>S7</address1>
                    <city>Coimbatire</city>
                    <country>IN</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>Sai Akshya Appartment</address1>
                    <city>Sanagoor Road</city>
                    <postalCode>631009</postalCode>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1> No 3</address1>
                    <city>Thenkaasi</city>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 98</address1>
                    <city>Bridh'Sanagoor Road</city>
                    <country>SriLanka</country>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
            </addresses>
        </Program>
    </Channel>
</xml>
```

Thank you all.

**Copied from comment:**
I doing like this

```
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@XMLValue", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xmlDetails.ToString();
```

Comment: How exactly are sending this XML to the stored procedure? How are you handling it in there?

Comment: If you're using **properly** parametrized queries - apostrophe's shouldn't really be a problem.... we need to see your code which **handles** this XML - how are you inserting the data into SQL Server??

Comment: I doing like this 

SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@XMLValue", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xmlDetails.ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **Parameterized Queries** (Take a look at `SqlParameters`), you won't be having these issues.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@ParamName";
param.Value         = valueVariable;
```

try not to use string concatenation and be aware of the risks and the implications.

**EDIT:**

`xmlDetails.ToString()` dont convert xmlDetails to string. Instead parse it

```
SqlXml newXml = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader("MyTestStoreData.xml")); 

SqlXml newXml = new SqlXml(xmlDetails); <-- xmlDetails is needed to be either Stream or XmlReader type
```

Comment: SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@XMLValue", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xmlDetails.ToString();